# Get Arraylist file json using java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have problems with my code, I need to extract the "materias" markup in the arraylist. Example data:

```
[{
    "name": "A114",
    "grupo": "DAW2",
    "tutor": 15,
    "materias": ["DWES", "DWEC", "IW", "DAW", "IE"]
}]
```

I tried this, work but i need the content of the arraylist:

```
try { // this read the JSON file
    line = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("fileAulas")));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
JSONArray recs = new JSONArray(line);
for (Object rec : recs) {

    Aula datos = new Aula();

    JSONObject obj = ((JSONObject) rec);
    String name = obj.getString("name");    
    //datos.setNombre(name);

    String grupo = obj.getString("grupo");
    //datos.setGrupo(grupo);

    int tutor = obj.getInt("tutor");
    //datos.setTutor(tutor);
}
```

My objetive is to read the arraylist and then `datos.setArraylist` to my another class. All works fine except read the arraylist

PD: I use java downloaded from Maven, to execute i use "javac -cp ./*: program.java"

Comment: What is rec and where does it come from?

Comment: I update the code

Answer (score 1):

`materias` is also an array, so you need something like:

```java
JSONArray materias = obj.getJsonArray("materias");
List<String> materiasList = materias.getValuesAs(String.class);
```

This is not type-safe so you need to make sure the array will only have String values.

Also, if you are using Java 8, you can iterate over the values and store them manually (`JsonArray` is also a `Collection<JsonValue>`)

Comment: sorry, but how i can read (or see) the content of that array? ¡thanks for advance!

Comment: Hi @UsuarioConMiga just edited, you can iterate directly over a JsonArray. It is a Java Collection :)

Answer (score 1):

Quickly created short test implementation of your needs:

```
    String json = "[{ \"name\":\"A114\",\"grupo\": \"DAW2\",\"tutor\":15,\"materias\": [\"DWES\",\"DWEC\",\"IW\",\"DAW\",\"IE\"]}]";

    JSONArray objectArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int x = 0; x < objectArray.length(); x++) {
        JSONObject obj = objectArray.getJSONObject(x);

        System.out.println("Name: " + obj.get("name"));
        System.out.println("Grupo: " + obj.get("grupo"));
        System.out.println("Tutor: " + obj.get("tutor"));

        JSONArray materias = obj.getJSONArray("materias");
        for (int y = 0; y < materias.length(); y++) {
            System.out.println("Materia " + y + ": " + materias.get(y));
        }
    }
```

Output

Name: A114
Grupo: DAW2
Tutor: 15
Materia 0: DWES
Materia 1: DWEC
Materia 2: IW
Materia 3: DAW
Materia 4: IE

Answer (score 0):

First gotta make your JSON Valid.

```
[{
        "name": "A114",
        "grupo": "DAW2",
        "tutor": 15,
        "materias": ["DWES", "DWEC", "IW", "DAW", "IE"]
    }]
```

Secondly, you can try the following :

```
for (JsonElement rec : recs) {

    Aula datos = new Aula();

    JSONObject obj = rec.getAsJsonObject();
    String name = obj.get("name").getAsString();    
    //datos.setNombre(name);

    String grupo = obj.get("grupo").getAsString();
    //datos.setGrupo(grupo);

    int tutor = obj.get("tutor").getAsInt();

     JsonObject obj = rec.getAsJsonObject();
      JsonArray materias = obj.getAsJsonArray("materias");

          List<String> materiasList = new ArrayList<>();

for (JsonElement item:
                 materias) {
                materiasList.add(item.getAsString());
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the syntax for an array in json is different that what you have in your file. For example - a simple complete json that contains an array of simple elements would be:

```
    {"contacts":[
      { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
      { "firstName":"Jen", "lastName":"Smith" },
      { "firstName":"David", "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]}
```

In your text, you specify an array, without the opening and closing JSON '{' and '}'. Also, You would need to name the array element ("contacts" in the example above). I think that what you want would be (I used "arrayName" for the array element name):

```
    {"arrayName":[{ "name":"A114","grupo": "DAW2","tutor":15,"materias":["DWES","DWEC","IW","DAW","IE"] }, 
      { "name":"121","grupo": "DAW1","tutor":8,"materias":["PROGRA","BD","SIS","LM","FOL"] }, 
      { "name":"A112","grupo": "AUTO1","tutor":5 }, 
      { "name":"A127","grupo": "ASIR1","tutor":2 }, 
      { "name":"A114","grupo": "SMR2","tutor":11 }, 
      { "name":"A128","grupo": "ASIR2","tutor":9,"materias":["IAW","ABD","ASIS","SI","IE"] }, 
      { "name":"A125","grupo": "ADM2","tutor":12 } ] }
```